# C# How to get list of database from Azure Cosmos

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I wonder there is anyway to get a list of all database from Azure Cosmos. I see a possible solution is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-databases) . However if I only know the Connection String, is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: You mean without a Cosmos account?  I doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like below. It makes use of [`v3 of Cosmos DB .Net SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos).

```
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("cosmos-db-connection-string");
            using (FeedIterator<DatabaseProperties> iterator = client.GetDatabaseQueryIterator<DatabaseProperties>())
            {
                while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (DatabaseProperties db in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(db.Id);
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can find more samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples.